# Help choosing a martial art

Tags: training

I am a total begginer and would like to pick and train a martial art.

I am 6 foot tall 165 lbs. I go to the gym regularly and have been lifting free-weights for about a year now.

My only criteria really are:

-Is highly applicable in real life situations

-Has sparring which doesn't involve getting hit in the head regularly (if at all)

note: I don't have problem with sparring in general,just the head hitting part

Comment: Welcome to the site @marko. Currently your question is too broad and not really answerable. I encourage you to check [previous similar questions](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/search?q=choose+martial+art+is%3Aquestion). If you can have a think about it then edit your question and add more detail then we can look at re-opening it.